# UWP Button with Content missing clicks in User Control

Tags: xaml, uwp, binding

I have a very simple user control that shows a number and has two buttons, one that increments the number, and one that decrements it. I am having a strange issue where my button will only seem to register a click and increment the value every other click. However, if I click way out on the edge of the button, it will capture every click and increment as expected. I have also noticed if I remove the mouse from hovering over the button between each click, it will capture all of my clicks. So, it seems to be something with regards to clicking on the content inside the button that is causing the issue, but that's as far as I've been able to narrow it down.

Edit: Some more info I just noticed is on clicks when it doesn't register, the button doesn't even depress. So it's like the UI doesn't see my mouse click at all.

Main page usage of the control:

```
  <controls:SetpointControl Grid.Column="0" Setpoint="{Binding SetpointConfig.HeatSetpoint}"/>
                <controls:SetpointControl Grid.Column="1" Setpoint="{Binding SetpointConfig.CoolSetpoint}" />
```

User Control XAML:

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SetpointChangeButton"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    Text
                    <!--<Viewbox>
                        <Polygon Points="512,345.8 435.6,422.2 256,230.8 77.2,422.2 0,345.8 256,89.8"
                                 Fill="White">
                        </Polygon>
                      <TextBlock Text="TEST"/>
                    </Viewbox>-->
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SetpointCntrl}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0"
            Style="{StaticResource SetpointChangeButton}"
            Command="{Binding IncrementPressedCommand}">
    </Button>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               FontSize="20"
               Foreground="White"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Text="{Binding Setpoint}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Style="{StaticResource SetpointChangeButton}"
            Command="{Binding DecrementPressedCommand}">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Edit:
[Link to git repo](https://github.com/Greg-Freeman/thermostat)

Requested code behind:

```
namespace ThermostatGui.Shared.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class SetpointControl : UserControl
    {
        public SetpointControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int Setpoint
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(SetpointProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SetpointProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SetpointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Setpoint", typeof(int), typeof(SetpointControl), new PropertyMetadata(23) { });

        private ICommand _incrementPressedCommand;
        public ICommand IncrementPressedCommand => _incrementPressedCommand ?? new RelayCommand(() => { Setpoint++; Debug.WriteLine("INCREMENT CLICKED"); });

        private ICommand _decrementPressedCommand;

        public ICommand DecrementPressedCommand => _decrementPressedCommand ?? new RelayCommand(() => { Setpoint--; Debug.WriteLine("DECREMENT CLICKED"); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code too?

Comment: Yes, I will this evening

Comment: It will be better if you could share the detailed code from the code-behind.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Please see edit

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue with the code you post. In my test, every click will trigger the command. Could you please share an [mcve] in Github or OneDrive. Please note that do not share the full project of your app.